# Master, Slave: Politically Correct Version

Tags: relationships

What other tech synonyms are there for a master-slave relationship? The situation is a knob that controls other knobs, or a button that controls other buttons.

Comment: Now that I think about it, this is probably better asked on http://english.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: @Frustrated I don't think this has anything to do with EL&U, since the terms suggested have to make sense in a technical sense as well, but I'll check with a mod there to make sure.

Comment: This question is attracting some seriously junky answers: the best place for single-word (or in this case, double-word) requests is English.SE, where you'll likely have a better time getting people to provide useful explanations as to why one pair of words is better than another.

Comment: @Robert (and everyone else): if you want to discuss the finer points of offensive language, use [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21). If you don't agree with the premise of the question, feel free to down-vote.

Comment: Related discussion on English usage StackExchange: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/204357/36249

Answer (score 12):

You could go with "Parent" and "Child". I guess "Manager" and "Worker" are also possible, though I don't see that nearly as often. Also possible is "Controller" and "Controllee" though that sounds weird, and I'm not even sure if "Controlee" is a word.

On the fun side of things, you could try something like "Overlord" and "Minion". Or "Hero" and "Sidekick". Or "BigBoss" and "Lackey". Or "Captain" and "Sailor". ;)

Comment: I could live with that last one ;)

Comment: Apart from that, when talking in HDD context, primary/secondary might actually work.

Comment: @Rook: Sailors will be offended.

Comment: @Robert - You serious? Why? ...

Comment: @Rook: Not serious.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesign, I've also been thinking about "supercontrol" and "subcontrol" (or "underling"). Thanks for thinking about this, it definitely helps. +1

Comment: Controller/Controlled

Answer (score 9):

Are you talking about master & slave as used for hard disks? In this case, **master & slave are actually a politically correct terms** to use. It would also be politically correct to apply those terms to software parts.

Otherwise, you may use some terms depending on the context: primary & secondary, parent & child, etc.

Comment: "Slave" as in "slavishly following".

Comment: I think master/slave is fine as long as SATA has a safe word!

Answer (score 4):

How about Parent / Child(ren) ?